# Jaxb XmlElementRef parent class tag

Tags: jakarta-ee, jaxb

I need some help in JAXB XmlElementRef tag generation. I have classes like following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
public class BaseRequest
{
   @XmlAttribute(name = "requestid")
   private String requestId;
   //Getters and Setters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ChildRequest")
public class ChildRequest extends BaseRequest
{
  private String name = null;
  private String id = null;
  //Setters and getters
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "PublishRequest")
public class PublishRequest
{
    private List<BaseRequest>   requests  = null;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Requests")
    @XmlElementRefs({ @XmlElementRef(type = ChildRequest.class) })
    public List<BaseRequest> getRequests()
    {
      return this.requests;
    }

}
```

And am expecting following XML out of these classes.

```
  <PublishRequest>
    <Requests>
      <Request requestid = "">
        <ChildRequest>
           <name></name>
           <id></id>
        </ChildRequest>
      </Request>
    </Requests>
  </PublishRequest>
```

But @XmlElementRef is ignoring parent class attributes and their declared JAXB annotations. 
Can anyone please help me to generate the expected output.

Comment: Show the output xml that you get now.

Comment: It is generating 

<PublishRequest>
         <Requests>
           <ChildRequest>
               <name></name>
               <id></id>
            </ChildRequest>
        </Requests>
  </PublishRequest>

Without Request Tag

Comment: Any idea how to solve this issue !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the classes using xjc:

```
xjc -p <your package> <your XSD>
```

For your scenario, following is the xsd for your XML:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="PublishRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Requests">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="Request">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="ChildRequest">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="name"/>
                          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="id"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="requestid"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

ObjectFactory class:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2012.09.25 at 11:57:53 AM GMT+05:30 
//


package com.test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;


/**
 * This object contains factory methods for each 
 * Java content interface and Java element interface 
 * generated in the com.test package. 
 * <p>An ObjectFactory allows you to programatically 
 * construct new instances of the Java representation 
 * for XML content. The Java representation of XML 
 * content can consist of schema derived interfaces 
 * and classes representing the binding of schema 
 * type definitions, element declarations and model 
 * groups.  Factory methods for each of these are 
 * provided in this class.
 * 
 */
@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {


    /**
     * Create a new ObjectFactory that can be used to create new instances of schema derived classes for package: com.test
     * 
     */
    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PublishRequest }
     * 
     */
    public PublishRequest createPublishRequest() {
        return new PublishRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest }
     * 
     */
    public PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest createPublishRequestRequestsRequestChildRequest() {
        return new PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PublishRequest.Requests.Request }
     * 
     */
    public PublishRequest.Requests.Request createPublishRequestRequestsRequest() {
        return new PublishRequest.Requests.Request();
    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link PublishRequest.Requests }
     * 
     */
    public PublishRequest.Requests createPublishRequestRequests() {
        return new PublishRequest.Requests();
    }

}
```

PublishRequest class:

```
//
// This file was generated by the JavaTM Architecture for XML Binding(JAXB) Reference Implementation, vJAXB 2.1.10 in JDK 6 
// See <a href="http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb">http://java.sun.com/xml/jaxb</a> 
// Any modifications to this file will be lost upon recompilation of the source schema. 
// Generated on: 2012.09.25 at 11:57:53 AM GMT+05:30 
//


package com.test;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;


/**
 * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
 * 
 * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
 * 
 * <pre>
 * &lt;complexType>
 *   &lt;complexContent>
 *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *       &lt;sequence>
 *         &lt;element name="Requests">
 *           &lt;complexType>
 *             &lt;complexContent>
 *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                 &lt;sequence>
 *                   &lt;element name="Request">
 *                     &lt;complexType>
 *                       &lt;complexContent>
 *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                           &lt;sequence>
 *                             &lt;element name="ChildRequest">
 *                               &lt;complexType>
 *                                 &lt;complexContent>
 *                                   &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
 *                                     &lt;sequence>
 *                                       &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                                       &lt;element name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
 *                                     &lt;/sequence>
 *                                   &lt;/restriction>
 *                                 &lt;/complexContent>
 *                               &lt;/complexType>
 *                             &lt;/element>
 *                           &lt;/sequence>
 *                           &lt;attribute name="requestid" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
 *                         &lt;/restriction>
 *                       &lt;/complexContent>
 *                     &lt;/complexType>
 *                   &lt;/element>
 *                 &lt;/sequence>
 *               &lt;/restriction>
 *             &lt;/complexContent>
 *           &lt;/complexType>
 *         &lt;/element>
 *       &lt;/sequence>
 *     &lt;/restriction>
 *   &lt;/complexContent>
 * &lt;/complexType>
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 */
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "requests"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "PublishRequest")
public class PublishRequest {

    @XmlElement(name = "Requests", required = true)
    protected PublishRequest.Requests requests;

    /**
     * Gets the value of the requests property.
     * 
     * @return
     *     possible object is
     *     {@link PublishRequest.Requests }
     *     
     */
    public PublishRequest.Requests getRequests() {
        return requests;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the value of the requests property.
     * 
     * @param value
     *     allowed object is
     *     {@link PublishRequest.Requests }
     *     
     */
    public void setRequests(PublishRequest.Requests value) {
        this.requests = value;
    }


    /**
     * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
     * 
     * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
     * 
     * <pre>
     * &lt;complexType>
     *   &lt;complexContent>
     *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *       &lt;sequence>
     *         &lt;element name="Request">
     *           &lt;complexType>
     *             &lt;complexContent>
     *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                 &lt;sequence>
     *                   &lt;element name="ChildRequest">
     *                     &lt;complexType>
     *                       &lt;complexContent>
     *                         &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
     *                           &lt;sequence>
     *                             &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                             &lt;element name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
     *                           &lt;/sequence>
     *                         &lt;/restriction>
     *                       &lt;/complexContent>
     *                     &lt;/complexType>
     *                   &lt;/element>
     *                 &lt;/sequence>
     *                 &lt;attribute name="requestid" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
     *               &lt;/restriction>
     *             &lt;/complexContent>
     *           &lt;/complexType>
     *         &lt;/element>
     *       &lt;/sequence>
     *     &lt;/restriction>
     *   &lt;/complexContent>
     * &lt;/complexType>
     * </pre>
     * 
     * 
     */
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
        "request"
    })
    public static class Requests {

        @XmlElement(name = "Request", required = true)
        protected PublishRequest.Requests.Request request;

        /**
         * Gets the value of the request property.
         * 
         * @return
         *     possible object is
         *     {@link PublishRequest.Requests.Request }
         *     
         */
        public PublishRequest.Requests.Request getRequest() {
            return request;
        }

        /**
         * Sets the value of the request property.
         * 
         * @param value
         *     allowed object is
         *     {@link PublishRequest.Requests.Request }
         *     
         */
        public void setRequest(PublishRequest.Requests.Request value) {
            this.request = value;
        }


        /**
         * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
         * 
         * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
         * 
         * <pre>
         * &lt;complexType>
         *   &lt;complexContent>
         *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *       &lt;sequence>
         *         &lt;element name="ChildRequest">
         *           &lt;complexType>
         *             &lt;complexContent>
         *               &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
         *                 &lt;sequence>
         *                   &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *                   &lt;element name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
         *                 &lt;/sequence>
         *               &lt;/restriction>
         *             &lt;/complexContent>
         *           &lt;/complexType>
         *         &lt;/element>
         *       &lt;/sequence>
         *       &lt;attribute name="requestid" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string" />
         *     &lt;/restriction>
         *   &lt;/complexContent>
         * &lt;/complexType>
         * </pre>
         * 
         * 
         */
        @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
        @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
            "childRequest"
        })
        public static class Request {

            @XmlElement(name = "ChildRequest", required = true)
            protected PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest childRequest;
            @XmlAttribute
            protected String requestid;

            /**
             * Gets the value of the childRequest property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest }
             *     
             */
            public PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest getChildRequest() {
                return childRequest;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the childRequest property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest }
             *     
             */
            public void setChildRequest(PublishRequest.Requests.Request.ChildRequest value) {
                this.childRequest = value;
            }

            /**
             * Gets the value of the requestid property.
             * 
             * @return
             *     possible object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public String getRequestid() {
                return requestid;
            }

            /**
             * Sets the value of the requestid property.
             * 
             * @param value
             *     allowed object is
             *     {@link String }
             *     
             */
            public void setRequestid(String value) {
                this.requestid = value;
            }


            /**
             * <p>Java class for anonymous complex type.
             * 
             * <p>The following schema fragment specifies the expected content contained within this class.
             * 
             * <pre>
             * &lt;complexType>
             *   &lt;complexContent>
             *     &lt;restriction base="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}anyType">
             *       &lt;sequence>
             *         &lt;element name="name" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
             *         &lt;element name="id" type="{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string"/>
             *       &lt;/sequence>
             *     &lt;/restriction>
             *   &lt;/complexContent>
             * &lt;/complexType>
             * </pre>
             * 
             * 
             */
            @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
            @XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
                "name",
                "id"
            })
            public static class ChildRequest {

                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected String name;
                @XmlElement(required = true)
                protected String id;

                /**
                 * Gets the value of the name property.
                 * 
                 * @return
                 *     possible object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public String getName() {
                    return name;
                }

                /**
                 * Sets the value of the name property.
                 * 
                 * @param value
                 *     allowed object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public void setName(String value) {
                    this.name = value;
                }

                /**
                 * Gets the value of the id property.
                 * 
                 * @return
                 *     possible object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public String getId() {
                    return id;
                }

                /**
                 * Sets the value of the id property.
                 * 
                 * @param value
                 *     allowed object is
                 *     {@link String }
                 *     
                 */
                public void setId(String value) {
                    this.id = value;
                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thnanks for quick reply Anshu, But in my case there is not Requests class available. And i cannot create classes using xjc because classes are already defined.

Comment: The best practice to use JAXB is to generate the classes from an already defined _schema_. You define _schema_ first and then generate the classes. If you say that the classes are already defined, then my advice would be to regenerate correct classes on the basis of your schema.

Answer (score 0):

Use @XmlElement annotation in classes. updated your code below.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Request")
public class BaseRequest
{
    @XmlAttribute(name = "requestid")
    private String requestId;
    //Getters and Setters   
    @XmlElement(name = "ChildRequest")
    ChildRequest childRequest;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "ChildRequest")
public class ChildRequest extends BaseRequest
{
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name = null;
    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    private String id = null;
    //Setters and getters 
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "PublishRequest")
public class PublishRequest
{
    private List<BaseRequest>   requests  = null;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Requests")
    @XmlElementRefs({ @XmlElementRef(type = ChildRequest.class) })
    public List<BaseRequest> getRequests()
    {
        return this.requests;
    }
}
```